# Django Drop-down fields for foreign key to another database field

Tags: django

I am a Django beginner and I am having trouble using bootstrap drop-downs for foreign key use.

I have an input form for adding Providers (supplier, manufacturer, or both) for my purchasing website that has the following data structure:

```
class Provider(models.Model):
    provider_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    provider_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    provider_address = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    provider_email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
    provider_contact_01 = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    provider_contact_02 = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    provider_type = models.ForeignKey(ProviderType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

in which provider_type is a foreign key for table ProviderType that has the following data structure:

```
class ProviderType(models.Model):
    providertype_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    providertype_desc = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.providertype_desc
```

Dataset for ProviderType:

```
| providertype_id |    providertype_desc    |
---------------------------------------------
|       1         |         Supplier        |
|       2         |       Manufacturer      |
|       3         | Supplier & Manufacturer |
```

The problem is that I have used providertype_desc as the text in the drop down field, because it is more user friendly and has context, rather than providertype_Id, Code segment in html:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
  <label for="provider_type">Type of Provider</label>
  <select class="custom-select" id="provider_type" name="provider_type" aria-label="Example select with button addon">
    <option selected>Choose...</option>
    {% for prov_types in provider_types %}
      <option>{{prov_types.providertype_desc}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
</div>
```

But the POST sequence fails because the providertype_id needs to be returned instead of providertype_desc.

Looking for suggestions, please try to keep simple as I am still a beginner in Django.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really an HTML issue, you want to add a `value` to your options:

```html
<option value="{{prov_types.pk}}>{{prov_types.providertype_desc}}</option>
```